# how to bind bootstrap dropdown to html created in jquery and then appended

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to build some drop downs in jquery.  I am struggling with getting the 
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()  bound to my added html.

I created a fiddle here demonstrating the problem.
I would like the bottom drop downs to be identical to the upper drop downs.

I created the upper drop downs using plain html markup.
I created the bottom drop downs via jquery.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hLqkLxrm/

[fiddle describing problem](http://jsfiddle.net/hLqkLxrm/)

here is the javascript

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var nestedjson = '[';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"dogs","href":"#", "innerlist":[';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"pug","href":"pug"},'
    nestedjson += '{"name":"shitzu","href":"shitzu"}';
    nestedjson += ']},';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"rodents","href":"#", "innerlist":[';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"mouse","href":"a"},';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"rat","href":"b"},';
    nestedjson += '{"name":"gerbil","href":"c"}';
    nestedjson += ']}]';



    var parsedjson = JSON.parse(nestedjson);


    var myhtml = '<ul class="nav nav-pills">';


    $.each(parsedjson, function () {
        myhtml += '<li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">' + this.name + '<b class="caret"></b></a> ';
        myhtml += '<ul class="dropdown-menu>';
        $.each(this.innerlist, function () {
            myhtml += '<li><a tabindex="-1" href = "' + this.href + '">';
            myhtml += this.name + '</a></li>';
        });
        myhtml += '</ul>';
        myhtml += '</li>';
    });


    myhtml += '</ul>';


    $(myhtml).appendTo('body');

    // not sure how to bind the bootstrap dropdown to added components.
    // this is not working
    $('body').on("change", function () {
        alert('appended');
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
    
    


});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 2nd line of your `$.each` function the html is not correctly formed..

Change:

```
myhtml += '<ul class="dropdown-menu>';
```

To:

```
myhtml += '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
```

Also, you don't need to the body 'change' handler since Bootstrap data attributes will enable to dropdown to toggle.

**Demo**: http://www.bootply.com/kzXvjXuE5P

Comment: Is there a way I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Yes.. you click the checkmark on this left side of this answer